# I'm developing an iPad app in English version

Tags: localization, internationalization

I'm a programmer and developing an iPad app in English version.
But I'm not native speaker, so it's hard for me to use English words.
I want check if the following words are used the right way.

1. "Change Group Name"

   - When users click edit button to change group names, then popped up a window and the
     phrase will show top of it.
2. "Do you also want to delete all sites from the group?"

   - When users click delete button to delete a group, then the phrase shows up. Some groups
     include some sites's information, so the app asks if the user also want to delete the
     sites's information.
3. "Added to the "Home" group."

   - The above phrase appears after users add a site to "Home" group.

I want to know if the uses of the phrases are right in English grammar in general.
Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to move this to english.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For phrase #3 I would change it to "Added site to the "Home" group."

Comment: I'd remove the first `the` in your version of Phrase 2. It seems a bit unnecessary.

Comment: @Blender, I agree with you after I thought about it more.